# How to select which template to load on Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, symfony1

This is maybe a bad approach problem more than a technical issue, but in any case your suggestions are very valuable.

My website have two protected pages, **/home** and **/popup**, each of this pages requires a logged user. As you may know Symfony automatically redirects the non logged user to your login_path (in my case is just **/login**), so thats ok. The problem is, the user who tries to log in from the URL **/home** needs to see a template call **normal_login.html.php** and the users who tries to loggin using **/popup** will see **popup_login.html.php**.

My **/login** page is managed by my user controller, in there im just cheking for the header referer to see if the user comes from **/popup**:

```
    $previousUrl = $this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer'); 
    if(strpos($previousUrl, $this->generateUrl('done_punctis_popup'))) $popupref = true;
```

After the script finish, i just check the **popupref** flag and if its true i just return the popup template, and if not i return the normal template.

So far all very good and working (tested). The Symfony framework then handle the form submission from any of the templates and login the user redirecting him to the original intended protected page either **/home** or **/popup**.

Where is the fault you may ask? Well since the system is based on a referer value, if the user do not make a mistake in the login form everything goes ok, but if the input information is not right (bad password or username) the check_login script will redirect the user back to the login controller only problem this time the referer is NOT anymore **/home** or **/popup** but **/login_check**!! So now my controller does not know where the user came from so it does not know where template to return.

---

What do you think?

**EDIT (requested)**

### Controller

```
public function loginAction( )
{
    $popupref = false;
    $previousUrl = $this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer'); 
    if(strpos($previousUrl, $this->generateUrl('done_punctis_popup'))) $popupref = true;

    // Se è già loggato non deve vedere questa pagina quindi redirect
    if( $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER') && !$popupref)
        return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('done_punctis_user_homepage'));


    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // verifica di eventuali errori
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    if(!$popupref) {
        return $this->render('DonePunctisBundle:Pages:login.html.php', array(
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error
            ));
    } else {
        return $this->render('DonePunctisBundle:Popup:popupSignup.html.php', array(
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error
           ));
    }

}
```

### Security

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        remember_me:
            key: %secret%
            lifetime: 3600
            path: /
            domain: ~
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
```

**In the question I change some names just for having a more clear explanation, /home actally does not exist, in reality everything called that needs authorization use the normal template, just the calls from /popup need the popup template.**

PS. Users from /home or /popup are the same, /home and /popup are just two different ways to login in to my site.

Comment: It's logical to use `/login/modal/` and `/login/normal/`, instead of referrer, right? Referrer is clumsy and problematic to rely on anyways. As a safeguard, too, you might force a redirect to the full `/login/` if the referrer isn't what you expect.

Comment: @JaredFarrish what you suggest is just the same problem, if the credential are wrong /login_check will redirect the user to whatever is specified on the security.yml (in this case /login), then again the controller will not know what template to print

Comment: That's why I said to redirect to the full form if there's any question. `/login/normal/` is probably superfluous, too, if it's the standard full page login form. Using referrer seems more like a hack than a real solution.

Comment: i understand you dont like referer, i will change that you are right, but that does not solve the problem, is just changing the way i select which template to return, if the credentials are wrong the user will be redirected to /login and i NEED to know what template to display, i cant just send him to /login/normal or /login/popup without knowing how is he looking at the site (normal or in the popup)

Comment: In other words, your URL should depict what you're requesting, and the POST data what's to be processed. Referrer, as you're discovering, is transitory, so it's unreliable, but you should be able to modify the URL in the popup request.

Comment: Right. In popup, *modify the URL* then *observe it instead of referrer* to determine if the request is model (fragment) or full request.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your idea as a answer, im interested on how you will write the controller.

Comment: Can you provide the full controller? Are you using FOSUserBundle?

Comment: give a minute to edit the answer

Comment: @JaredFarrish you can check now. I also add part of the security.yml

Comment: Are you using annotations in `loginAction()`?

Comment: For instance, I would think you have a `loginModalAction()` with a `@Route("/login/modal")` as it's depicted [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-method), which could set a `isModal` class variable to `true` before subrouting back to `loginAction()`, which would then `if ($this->isModal)...` instead of the referrer. So as long as you use `/login/modal` or whatnot from within your popup, that seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: Or, minimally, you could use [`getPathInfo()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getPathInfo) as seen [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/blob/master/Admin/PageAdmin.php#L346), and just check if `$this->getRequest()->getPathInfo() == '/login/modal'` That would replace the referrer condition.

Comment: that seems the way to go, but what should i put on login_path?

Comment: Domingo.. In Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler, it shows how it's storing the referrer URL before redirecting login.  Check that out. Edit: DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler

Comment: @Mike the problem is that i dont want to change the symfony core

Comment: I know, of course not.. But you'll get an idea of where it's storing the redirect path.

Comment: Right. Use a GET variable instead: `/login?modal=true`, and then `$this->getRequest()->get('modal')` instead.

Comment: But if login_check fails (bad credentials) it will redirect the user to login_path right? thats how symfony works.

Comment: that means we are at the start again, I use my controller to know if modal is set, i select the appropriated template, the user fail the login, symfony redirect him to the login_path which is /login, then again i lost the get var

Comment: Alright, I didn't want to break this one out, but in the client you could set a header flag on the AJAX request, or put a form hidden element tagging it. I understand your conundrum.

Comment: Aha! Inspecting the [Sonata demo](http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/sonata/user/user/create), I trapped and inspected the request for an async modal form, and it has `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` set. So instead of `referer` header, you could `$this->getRequest()->headers->get('X-Requested-With')`.

Comment: Domingo, is the popup done via ajax?  Had you mentioned that from the get-go, this would've been pretty simple.

Comment: this end up becoming to munch complicate, id just made some modification to the core https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/5860/files

Comment: And... https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/blob/master/CmsManager/DecoratorStrategy.php#L65 Have you inspected your popup AJAX request headers with Chrome Console or Firebug? I think jQuery actually automatically adds `X-Requested-With`. That's *really, really easy* if it's already present. You were just looking at the wrong header, more or less.